# Privately sharing variable only between two classes - Java

Tags: java

I have a package that contains two classes. Private variable `share` is located in `class A` and that variable can be accessed only by these two classes, `A` and `B`, and can't be accessed by importing the package. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
// A.java    
class A {
    private static String share;

}

// B.java
class B {
    public String myMethode() {
        // do something with share
    }
}
```

Comment: if you make `share` protected and have `Class B` extend `Class A`.

Comment: make `share` package private and you´re already there.

Comment: Put `A` and `B` in the same package with no other classes, and make `share` package-private (i.e. no visibility modifier).

Comment: You could write a getter for share that requires a B as parameter and sets a share-attribute in B.

Comment: When using private, you can't. That is the whole point of making things  `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve it directly.
There are visibility levels in Java:

**public** - visible from any other classes

**protected** - visible in all classes who extend a class
  so if in Class A you have

```
class A {
  protected String share;
}
```

it will be visible in `class B extends A`, `class C extends B` and so on...
  then there is a possibility to create another `class D extends A` and `share` will be visible in it. Unless `class A` is final, but with that you cannot have needed `class B extends A`

**package visible**

```
package com.foo.myclasses;
class A {
  String share;
}
```

with that `share` will be visible in all classes in the package `com.foo.myclasses`
So still there is a way to create a class in the same package and `share` will be visible in it.

You may do a Work around to achieve that.

make `private String share` in class A

create `protected getShare()` (or package visible) method
 and check the class like

```
protected String getShare() {
  if (this.getClass().getName().equals("com.foo.myclasses.A") or this.getClass().getName().equals("com.foo.myclasses.B")) {
      return share;
  } else
  {
      throw new IllegalAccessException(this.getClass().getName() + " is not allowed to access share);
     // or return null
  }
}
```

But it is about access to the value of share at run time. Nothing prevents access (as above) in the code. Code will compile, but throws exception at run time.

It is what it is.