# Java: Accessing variables from other classes

Tags: java, class, extends

I am fairly new to java and was wondering, if I had a two classes as follows:

```
public class Class {
    char[][] charArray = new charArray[100[10];
}
class OtherClass extends Class {

}
```

Would the OtherClass class be able to access charArray? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: DId you try anything to test it? WHat happened then?

Comment: Well char[][] charArray is instance variable, so in order to access it from OtherClass you have to instantiate an object first.

Comment: Google for getters and setters in Java

Comment: Also google for encapsulation and OO :-)

Comment: learn 1.Inheritance 2.Access specifiers 3.non Access modfiers

Comment: Yes you can accces, create a new object from OtherClass. OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(); otherClass.charArray. By the way you code won't compile. There is no such type charArray.

Comment: Yes. You could learn about visibility about Java class members here -
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look at answer here: [sharing-variable-only-between-two-classes-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575617/privately-sharing-variable-only-between-two-classes-java/47576222#47576222)

Question is slightly different, but in answer there is basic about visibility in Java.

In short:

for your example `charArray` from Class will be visible from OtherClass only if both classes are in the same package.

To make it visible by child classes from any package it must be either `public char[][] charArray` or `protected char[][] charArray`